# How to turn a Number.txt file to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am suppose to fix the logical and syntax errors in the code which i did once but i reset the code thinking it was wrong, and haven't been able to figure it out since.

I added line = line.split to the code, also changed numbers.append to numbers.sort, and changed int( I understand why int does not work but I am not sure what to replace it with) to input.

main.py

```
number_file=open("Numbers.txt")
count=0
numbers = []
sum = 0

for line in "Numbers.txt"
```

---

Numbers.txt

```
0
50
100
```

Comment: This code isn't complete, it's not merely wrong, it doesn't directly express the goal in the first place. What is it supposed to *do*? What is the result expected from your example input? Have you talked to your professor or a TA (or read any of the Python docs), because if you think `numbers.append` and `number.sort` (neither of which appears in your code, so I don't know how you changed one to the other) are interchangeable, you clearly need one on one help to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but here is an answer based on my understanding of your question:

```
# Create a list named numbers
numbers = []

# Open the input file in read only
with open ('Numbers.txt', 'r') as input:
  # read each line of the input file
  for line in input:
    # append each line to the list numbers
    # rstrip removes the \n from the strings
    numbers.append(line.rstrip())


print (type(numbers))
# outputs
<class 'list'>

print (numbers)
# outputs
['0', '50', '100']

# converts your list elements to int for summing 
results = list(map(int, numbers))
print (sum(results))
# outputs
150
```

If this is not correct please let me know and I will adjust my answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck with your coding and don't get discouraged, because it takes lots of failures to become proficient.

Answer (score -1):

A good way to open a file is to use the context:

```
with open('path/to/file/Numbers.txt','r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        do_stuff # knowing that they are string so you should convert to int
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it's basically a comment on how to open and iterate files that is essentially unrelated to the question. Side-note: Never do `for line in input_file.readlines():`; that just forces you to slurp the whole file into a temporary `list` in memory before processing it, run through the `list`, then throw it away (wasteful in general, and very bad for huge files), when `for line in input_file:` accomplishes the same goal by lazily iterating a line at a time, with much lower memory overhead and quicker response time.

Comment: I felt that it was the help he needed, when looking at his code. Just giving him a code that works was counter productive. I apologize if you don't feel that way